# Object detection using faster r-cnn with multiple classes in single image

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to use the faster R-CNN algorithm (I have successfully run this tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) and am now building a dataset of my own.

The dataset in this tutorial has around 1000 images per class, with each image containing exactly one example from its class.

Being unfamiliar with the details of the implementation, I'm wondering if its possible to have multiple classes in a single training image? The annotation file would end up looking something like:

```
<annotation>
<folder>images</folder>
<filename>example-filename.jpg</filename>
<size>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>677</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>
      **CLASS_1**
    </name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <occluded>0</occluded>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>741</xmin>
        <ymin>320</ymin>
        <xmax>921</xmax>
        <ymax>492</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
<object>
    <name>
      **CLASS_2**
    </name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <occluded>0</occluded>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>479</xmin>
        <ymin>255</ymin>
        <xmax>740</xmax>
        <ymax>489</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

The reason I wonder is that the script that converts annotations to TFRecords has the following code:

```
feature_dict = {
      'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
      'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(
          data['filename'].encode('utf8')),
      'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(
          data['filename'].encode('utf8')),
      'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
      'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
      'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
      'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
      'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
      'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
      'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
      'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
      'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
      'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(difficult_obj),
      'image/object/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
      'image/object/view': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(poses),
  }

  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
```

**I tried it and...**

So to add a bit to this, I tried training a model with 3 classes distributed at random across about 600 images (many images had 1-2 examples of all three classes) and after about 3 hours saw that the loss decreased but when I actually ran inference on the eval images nothing was detected. Is there some kind of relationship between the number of classes and the required training time?

Comment: Multiple classes per image is the standard object detection setting, it should not be a problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thank you. I ran the training algorithm for about 6k iterations and the loss function converged to a small number but no classes were detected in my eval images. How might I know if it's a case of not training for long enough? training on cloud GPUs is a bit pricey so want to limit my guessing

Comment: There can be many reasons for this. First one might be that the `tfrecord` making script is wrong. Other might be that the inference script might be wrong. Also, one might be that the training needs to be done for more time, like a day or two.

Comment: Did you build on top of a pre-trained model? See here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md#downloading-a-coco-pretrained-model-for-transfer-learning

Comment: @AnshKumar turns out I just needed to train for longer. 4 hours wasn't enough. I let it run for a full day and got better results.